# ¿Como hago para que no se duplique un frame en Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un Sistema de ventas en Python, tengo un frame con todos los botones que llevan a diferentes frames cada uno y cuando aprieto los botones para verlos me los muestra perfectamente excepto el de ventas. cada vez que toco el boton se duplica el frame con todo su contenido y por mas que cambie de frame no se borra y se duplica este es el codigo de esa parte porfa si alguien me puede ayudar es para una tarea que debo entregar y es lo unico que me falta. El frame de ventas tiene un Treeview que puse para se vean los articulos que se van a vender y diferentes entrys para completar con la información de cada producto, tambien tiene un boton de buscar para no tener que llenar los campos en caso de que no se quiera. Me dijeron que una solucion puede ser el agregar un boton de salir pero no me gusta como se ve estéticamente ademas de que los botones para cambiar de frame se ven todo el tiempo.

```
def verVentas():
limpiarFrames()
frameVentas.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
def venta():
    carrito = []
    #frames
    frameTabla = Frame(frameVentas, bg=colorBase2)
    frameTabla.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    frameArticulos = Frame(frameVentas,bg=colorBase)
    frameArticulos.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    #tabla venta treeview
    tablaVentas = ttk.Treeview(frameTabla)
    tablaVentas["columns"] = ("subtotal","iva","total")
    tablaVentas.column("#0",width=10)
    tablaVentas.column("subtotal",width=10)
    tablaVentas.column("iva",width=10)
    tablaVentas.column("total",width=10)
    tablaVentas.heading("#0",text="Detalle")
    tablaVentas.heading("subtotal",text="Subtotal")
    tablaVentas.heading("iva",text="IVA")
    tablaVentas.heading("total",text="Total")
    tablaVentas.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1,pady=(20,40),padx=10)
    #conexion

    #agregar articulos
    entryBuscar = Entry(frameArticulos,font=("League Gothic",12))
    entryBuscar.pack()
    def buscarArticulo():
        tabla = conexion.cursor()
        buscar = (entryBuscar.get(),)
        tabla.execute("SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE id=?",buscar)
        datos = tabla.fetchall()
        tabla.close()
        if(len(datos)>0):
            for dato in datos:
                entryId.insert(0,dato["id"])
                entryDetalle.insert(0,dato["detalle"])
                entryStock.insert(0,dato["stock"])
                entryPrecio.insert(0,dato["precio"])
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Venta","Articulo no encontrado")
    botonBuscar = Button(frameArticulos, text="Buscar",
                        command=buscarArticulo, bg=colorVerde2,
                        font=("League Gothic",12),fg=colorGris2,
                        relief=FLAT,width=15)
    botonBuscar.pack(pady=(0,20))
    labelId = Label(frameArticulos,text="ID",
                    font=("League Gothic",12),bg=colorBase)
    labelId.pack(pady=(10,0))
    entryId = Entry(frameArticulos,font=("League Gothic",12))
                    #,state="readonly")
    entryId.pack()
    labelDetalle = Label(frameArticulos,text="Detalle",
                    font=("League Gothic",12),bg=colorBase)
    labelDetalle.pack(pady=(10,0))
    entryDetalle = Entry(frameArticulos,font=("League Gothic",12))
                    #,state="readonly")
    entryDetalle.pack()
    labelStock = Label(frameArticulos,text="Stock",
                    font=("League Gothic",12),bg=colorBase)
    labelStock .pack(pady=(10,0))
    entryStock  = Entry(frameArticulos,font=("League Gothic",12))
                    #,state="readonly")
    entryStock .pack()
    labelPrecio = Label(frameArticulos,text="Precio",
                    font=("League Gothic",12),bg=colorBase)
    labelPrecio .pack(pady=(10,0))
    entryPrecio = Entry(frameArticulos,font=("League Gothic",12))
                    #,state="readonly")
    entryPrecio.pack()
    labelCantidad= Label(frameArticulos,text="Cantidad",
                font=("League Gothic",12),bg=colorBase,fg=colorGris2)
    labelCantidad.pack(pady=(10,0))
    entryCantidad = Entry(frameArticulos,font=("League Gothic",12))
    entryCantidad.pack()
venta()
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque te falta tabular las líneas de código de ver Ventas:

```
def verVentas():
limpiarFrames()
frameVentas.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
```

Comment: Dudo que sea eso. Si fuera eso, Python le hubiera mandado un error. Se que es engañoso, pero en ocasiones, los op copian mal el código en las preguntas resultando en código mal indentado.

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario ver lo que hay en tu funcion limpiarFrames() porque parece no estar funcionando.

Pero una opcion diferente es usar ttk.Notebook
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
con esta libreria podras crear pestañas en tu programa y cambiarte facilmente entre frames.
pero no habia vista que tienes problemas de indentacion.